# Type of usage with descriptions/accuracy

Tags: word-usage, commas

> Sarah Smith as Melanie Cross, a teenager whose parents are outside of
>   the site; younger brother of Angie.
>
> Sarah Smith as Melanie Cross, a local widow of a hoarder; suspicious
>   about the numerous propane trucks coming into town.
>
> Melanie Cross as Sarah Smith, *who is leading a new campaign to
>   abolish the use of sugar in ice cream.

On these cast descriptions you commonly see for tv shows and films, are they considered fragments as the don't work as complete sentences even though they end with a period? The unrestrictive relative clause technically can't end with a period.

*Also would you class the semi-colon usage as informal.* It cannot join  incomplete sentences in this way, right.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, those are to be considered fragments, or possibly elliptical sentences, because, as you say, they lack a main verb and aren't complete sentences. The cast is listed, so this is best treated as a list; in lists, sentence fragments are common, especially noun groups, as here.

The capital at the beginning of the fragment and the full stop at the end aren't uncommon either outside of full sentences; they seem normal to me in this context.

This list and the way it is phrased are somewhat informal, yes. Semicola *can* be used between fragments rather than full clauses, especially in an enumeration where the enumerated phrases are long or contain commas, in order to make the sentence easier to read. That is not the case here, but somehow the semicolon does not surprise me. I would say that a semicolon can also be used between fragments if the whole text is made up of fragments rather than full clauses, which is the case here. Sometimes, this will be a sign of informality. But compare the title of an academic paper, which is hardly informal, but which may include a semicolon (a title is often also a fragment):

> Double Titles
>
> For an alternative or double title in English beginning with or, we
>   follow the first example given in section 8.165 of The Chicago Manual
>   of Style and punctuate as follows:
>
> "*England’s Monitor; or, The History of the Separation (452)*"
>
> — https://style.mla.org/punctuation-with-titles/